# Docker Compose AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, aws-ecr

I have Docker Swarm of 3 manager nodes . Docker compose on the Primary Manager starting 4 microservices from AWS ECR registry( Have done awslogin on all the swarm nodes)

My Question:

Docker service start necessarily download the docker images from ECR into one of the Swarm nodes ? or based on checksum of the current running image and the image available on the registry run the latest image